# What are Best Practice Recommendations for Java EE 7 Property File Configuration?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, dependency-injection, wildfly-8

Where does application configuration belong in modern Java EE applications? What best practice(s) recommendations do people have?

By application configuration, I mean settings like connectivity settings to services on other boxes, including external ones (e.g. Twitter and our internal Cassandra servers...for things such as hostnames, credentials, retry attempts) as well as those relating business logic (things that one might be tempted to store as constants in classes, e.g. days for something to expire, etc).

Assumptions:

1. We are deploying to a Java EE 7 server (Wildfly 8.1) using a single EAR file, which contains multiple wars and one ejb-jar.
2. We will be deploying to a variety of environments: Unit testing, local dev installs, cloud based infrastructure for UAT, Stress testing and Production environments. **Many of  our properties will vary with each of these environments.**
3. We are not opposed to coupling property configuration to a DI framework if that is the best practice people recommend.
4. All of this is for new development, so we don't have to comply with legacy requirements or restrictions. We're very focused on the current, modern best practices.

Does configuration belong inside or outside of an EAR?

If *outside* of an EAR, where and how best to reliably access them?

If *inside* of an EAR we can store it anywhere in the classpath to ease access during execution. But we'd have to re-assemble (and maybe re-build) with each configuration change. And since we'll have multiple environments, we'd need a means to differentiate the files within the EAR. I see two options here:

1. Utilize expected file names (e.g. `cassandra.properties`) and then build multiple environment specific EARs (eg. `appxyz-PROD.ear`).
2. Build one EAR (eg. `appxyz.ear`) and put all of our various environment configuration files inside it, appending an environment variable to each config file name (eg `cassandra-PROD.properties`). And of course adding an environment variable (to the vm or otherwise), so that the code will know which file to pickup.

What are the best practices people can recommend for solving this common challenge?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know what is best practice, but here is what we do.

(Note however that this only works well for one installation per application per server and will fail when one wants to use multiple deployments per server, say for multitenancy deployments).

#### CDI injection of properties values

We use a somewhat sophisticated CDI injection approach to inject configuration values from `.properties` files directly into beans, like this:

```
@Inject @ConfigurationValue(value="amazonS3FileContentsAccessKey")
private String accessKey;
```

The corresponding `@Producer` bean reads configuration files from the class path and from a given "local" location:

#### global/local `.properties` files

1. Each EAR contains a "global" `.properties` file on the class path for configuration values that change seldom and/or usually remain consistent through environments (such as days for something to expire).  Further, the global configuration file contains sane default values (e.g. "`localhost`" for database server hostname).  The global  `properties` files (there are multiple, see below) are maintained in the source tree.
2. For every development environment/installation/server/deployment, there (possibly) is a "local" properties file that contains the local settings that overwrite the global configuration's settings, e.g., database names, passwords etc.

The expected path to "local" properties files is configured in the global configuration file (e.g., `/etc/myapp/local.properties`) or `C:\myapp\local.properties`.

Actually, we even allow substitution of some variables in the filename for the local configuration files, such as "`${hostname}`".  The original idea was that the local properties could also be maintained in some central source control by distinguishing them by hostname (`local.machineA.properties`, `local.machineB.properties`), but we don't use that at the moment, because our production settings are the same on all machines (Amazon S3 keys, database password/host etc).

#### Assembling for dev, testing, production

We assemble different EARs depending on the stage of development using Maven profiles.
On assemply, the desired `global.${profile.name}.properties` file (where `profile.name` is, e.g., `dev` or `production`) is copied to the expected `global.properties` file in the classpath.

For example, `dev` and `testing` share a common AmazonS3 secret/bucket, which is configured once for all developers in the `configuration.dev.properties` file, while the `configuration.production.properties` does not contain our production keys.

Furthermore, our `dev` and `testing` environments have debugging enabled and configured in, say `web.xml`, but of course `staging` and `production` have not.  Our `.properties`-based approach cannot change files such as `web.xml`, but with Maven build profiles it's easy.

Comment: Like your detailed answer.

Comment: Alexander: Many thanks for the detailed response. In a nutshell, it sounds like what you do is: 1) Assemble separate, environment specific EARs using Maven Profiles. 2) Use CDI to inject the values where needed. And 4) have a custom Producer method that knows where to pull the property values from (filename and location(s)).

Comment: Here is a nice full example of this: http://piotrnowicki.com/2012/06/inject-java-properties-in-java-ee-using-cdi/

Answer (score 0):

There can be many possible solutions to your question depending upon everyone's experience. So, why not let's try some already discussed ideas. Please have a look at

1. [Configure Java EE 6 for dev/QA/prod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10772263/configure-java-ee-6-for-dev-qa-prod)
2. [How to configure Java EE application to apply different settings](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/HowToConfigureJavaEEApplicationToApplyDifferentSettingsinWebxmlEtcForVariousEnvironmentsByMaven)

Hope these two will give you some common understanding of how you can build the whole environment by using maven.

Comment: That's not what the OP has asked for, he already wrote that they could possibly re-assemble the build for each environment, but that's not desired.