# How to get the value of the properties file in the @Pattern

Tags: java

doman ：

```
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:valid.properties")
public class Role implements Serializable {

@Id
private String id;

@Pattern(regexp = "^[a-zA-Z0-9_]{6,32}$")
private String name;
```

valid.properties :

```
username=^[a-zA-Z0-9_]{6,32}$
password=^[a-zA-Z]\w{5,17}$
email=^\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$
```

**regexp** value is fixed

modify @Pattern：

```
 @Pattern(regexp = "${username}")  // compile Error
 private String name;
```

**I want to replace regexp value, use properties instead **

how do ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not from external properties, but how about:

```
private static final String USERNAME = "^[a-zA-Z0-9_]{6,32}$";
private static final String PASSWORD = "^[a-zA-Z]\w{5,17}$";
private static final String EMAIL = "^\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$";

@Pattern(regexp = USERNAME)
private String name;

...
```

In Java EE 7 you can inject properties values like this:

```
@Inject @ConfigurationValue(value="username")
private String userName;
```

But I'm not sure you can then use that String in another JPA annotation just like that. Give it a try.
For details on use of `@ConfigurationValue` see for instance [What are Best Practice Recommendations for Java EE 7 Property File Configuration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26187763/what-are-best-practice-recommendations-for-java-ee-7-property-file-configuration)

Comment: Can anyone post a solution for this. I am also stuck on the same problem.